# Bundling remote modules with Vite

Tags: javascript, vite, es6-modules

I have an HTML file and some scripts that load some modules directly from `esm.sh`, e.g.

```js
import { x } from 'https://esm.sh/y'
```

When building with Vite, these dependencies are not downloaded / bundled, so when the page loads and the scripts are executed, then there is at least one additional request per such dependency (typically more since they get bounced around in `esm.sh`), reducing page load speed measurably.

I know the "standard" way is to simply install the modules and have the bundler bundle them properly. But I was wondering, if there is a way (for example a Vite plugin or some configuration) that would pre-download and bundle all such dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to bundle remote modules with Vite. You can use the vite-plugin-remote-assets plugin. This plugin will download and bundle all remote assets, including those from esm.sh.

To use the plugin, install it with the following command:

`npm install -D vite-plugin-remote-assets`

Then, add the following line to your Vite configuration file:

`plugins: ['vite-plugin-remote-assets']`

You can also configure the plugin to download and bundle specific assets, or to exclude certain assets. For more information, see the plugin documentation: https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-remote-assets

Here is an example of a Vite configuration file that uses the `vite-plugin-remote-assets` plugin:

```
//vite.config
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: ['vite-plugin-remote-assets'],
  remoteAssets: {
    assets: [
      'https://esm.sh/y',
    ],
    outputDir: 'assets',
  },
})
```

Or as it appears in the official documentation:

```
// vite.config.ts
import RemoteAssets from 'vite-plugin-remote-assets'

export default {
  plugins: [
    RemoteAssets()
  ]
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, does this plugin handle import graphs or would it just treat the modules as static assets? a typical export from esm.sh, even in bundled mode looks like `export * from "/v132/y@version/es2021/y.bundle.mjs"`, meaning merely downloading as if it was another static asset wouldn't help, as you would need to follow links and download and bundle the whole dependency graph.